# How to use Continuum to build from multiple branches

Tags: maven-2, continuous-integration, branch, continuum

I've got a project which is built using Maven and Continuum.  We've got several release branches, most of which are in retirement but any could conceivably be resurrected if an issue comes up.

My problem is that adding branches to Continuum is very heavyweight; the best method I've found so far is to add each branch as a separate project, but that involves a reasonable amount of setup.  As we don't make releases all that often, this is fine, but I'd like the ability to run Continuum against short-lived feature branches, and I don't want to have to set everything up by hand each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd like the ability to run Continuum against short-lived feature branches, and I don't want to have to set everything up by hand each time.

Maybe not the expected answer but my suggestion would be to change for another CI tool. Doing what you describe would be *extremely fast and easy* with Hudson for example (create a new maven2 project build, fill in the scm url and you're done).

Comment: We're now using gerrit and Jenkins, which does indeed resolve this particular issue we were having with Continuum.

Answer (score 0):

If those short-lived feature branches are not that important, you could change the SCM Url for the project to the SCM Url of the new feature branch you want to do continuous integration upon.  Unfortunately, Continuum does not track the SCM Url in the build history for each build, but it changing the SCM Url would provide what you need without creating a new project each time.